# angular material tabs does not highlight the active tab properly with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

list.html

```
<md-content sticky>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height>
            <md-tab label={{menu.name}} ng-repeat="menu in menuItems" ng-click="gotoDiv(menu.name)">
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
```

list.js

```
$scope.gotoDiv = function(x) {
                var newHash = 'anchor' + x;
                if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
                    $location.hash('anchor' + x);
                } else {
                    $anchorScroll();
                }
            };
```

So when ng-click is executed, it goes to perticular div perfectly, but it does not highlight the active/selected tab at all. So is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example and works in my browser, probably is a CSS issue.

check if you got the `.md-active` class in your angular material theme.

if you dont have it, you can add the `.md-active`  CSS code for tabs manually

```
md-tabs .md-tab.md-active {
    color: rgb(63,81,181);
}
.md-tab.md-active {
    cursor: default;
}
md-tab-item.md-tab {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but still active tab does not change color with ng-click